# select rows by a pattern on the index column

Tags: python, pandas

Please find below my input/output (desired):

##### Input :

```
        OBID    NAME   VALUE
0  ID-110503  Name 1    39.0
1  ID-110504  Name 2   243.5
2  ID-225930  Name 3  3212.0
3  ID-339630  Name 4   350.0
4  ID-117742  Name 5   785.0
```

After setting the column `OBID` as the index, I need to select all the rows (by using `df.loc`) that have an index matching the pattern `ID-11xxxx`.

##### Output (desired) :

```
             NAME  VALUE
OBID                    
ID-110503  Name 1   39.0
ID-110504  Name 2  243.5
ID-117742  Name 5  785.0
```

I'm sorry if this is a stupid and/or a duplicated question but here is (if needed) a reproducible example.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """OBID NAME    VALUE
ID-110503   Name 1  39
ID-110504   Name 2  243.5
ID-225930   Name 3  3212
ID-339630   Name 4  350
ID-117742   Name 5  785
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\t')
df.set_index('OBID', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways.

Can use `query` and find string that begins with the characters you want leveraging `str.contains`

```
df.query("OBID.str.contains('^ID-11')", engine='python')
```

Using loc

```
df.loc[df.index.str.contains('^ID-11'),:]
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked ! Is there a way to do the same with `df.loc` and/or `df.iloc` ?

Comment: Yes of course, df.loc[df.index.str.contains('^ID-11'),:]``

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df.iloc[:,num of rows].filter(regex= 'ID-11$',axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks YJR but It throws a `TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key`

Comment: No worries. Now it gives a `KeyError: 'OBID'`

Comment: Because you index the column may be iloc is fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df.index.str.startswith("ID-11")]
```